# Loud fans with only mild usage of Dell XPS15 9500

Tags: ubuntu, fan, dell-xps

I have a Dell XPS15 9500 machine, which is one year old at this point.

When I turn it on, after about 5 minutes of mild browsing, the fans crank up to full power and the bottom of the machine can get hot.

I've seen that other people have had a similar problem and I guess there's no solution, but I wanted to post on here at a last resort to see if anyone has some genius solution :)

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Do you have Dell repositories added and appropriate `oem-somerville-*-meta` package installed?

Comment: I don't know what they are so, I guess the answer is no. I will look into it though. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, I'm having a problem with Dell repositories. I will post another question about that and then come back to this one :D

Comment: You're trying to add repos dedicated for their enterprise server hardware. Try these instructions: https://askubuntu.com/a/1339499/129094 (except `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:boltgolt/howdy -y` and following lines, these are unrelated)

Comment: By the way, `melisa` is actually for XPS 9300, but it should be close enough and I wasn't able to find which codename is the correct one for 9500.

Comment: Sorry to be dumb, but the instructions you linked to - I am supposed to put them into the terminal line by line? Or does that green bit have to be kept together? I'm not sure what it's doing. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the green bit is one long string. Doing this line by line would work, but it would be a waste of time. The shell will support multiple lines at once.